# Async operation inside android library, which coroutineScope can I use?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I'm studing coroutines but every times I don't know how convert a java async architecture to a kotlin coroutines async architecture.

For example, there are different library which use the java executors inside of they. For instance Firebase to write the log on file uses an executor instantiated inside of the crashlytics library. Which is the correct way to do that with the kotlin coroutines ?
Where I create the coroutineScope ?

Comment: If the app might want to control the scope, you could accept a scope as a parameter, perhaps supplying a default value. Otherwise, you can create your own scope, just like how the Jetpack does for having scopes tied to things like `ViewModel` lifetime.

Comment: Thanks :) i was wondering if is the correct way to do. If I start an async operation in my apps library and the user shutdown the app, what does happen if I create a library own scope ?

Comment: I do not know how you are defining "shutdown the app". If you create your own scope, you are responsible for cleaning it up at an appropriate time. If there is no appropriate time -- the scope should remain active for the life of the process -- then there is nothing that you need to do. If the scope should be tied to something in the app (say, the lifecycle of an activity), accept the scope as a parameter and have the caller supply one. And if there is a logical lifecycle that would drive the use of the scope, clean up the scope yourself when it is no longer needed.

Comment: "shutdown the app": for me is when the user remove the app from the recent app screen.

Comment: On modern versions of Android, that usually terminates your process, and your coroutines, scopes, and everything else go away as a result. If you are trying to have your app's process survive that -- such as via a foreground service -- we're back to the suggestions from my previous comment.